# Python AES-256-CBC equivalent from PHP

Tags: python, php, encryption, aes

I found this algorithm that works very well for me to encrypt data between PHP and Flutter, I have looked for its equivalent in Python 3 but it gives me different results, will someone have a reference on how I can pass that function to its equivalent in Python?

```php
function encrypt( $string, $encrypt=true) {
    $secret_key = 'SuperSecretKey';
    $secret_iv = 'SuperSecretBLOCK';
    $output = false;
    $encrypt_method = "AES-256-CBC";
    $key = hash( 'sha256', $secret_key );
    $iv = substr( hash( 'sha256', $secret_iv ), 0, 16 );
    if($encrypt) {
        $output = base64_encode( openssl_encrypt( $string, $encrypt_method, $key, 0, $iv ) );
    } else {
        $output = openssl_decrypt( base64_decode( $string ), $encrypt_method, $key, 0, $iv );
    }
    return $output;
}
```

I tried this code but it gives me different results

```py
import base64
import hashlib
from Crypto.Cipher import AES


class AESCipher:
    def __init__(self, key, iv):
        self.key = hashlib.sha256(key.encode('utf-8')).digest()
        self.iv = hashlib.sha256(iv.encode('utf-8')).digest()[:16]

    __pad = lambda self, s: s + (AES.block_size - len(s) % AES.block_size) * chr(
        AES.block_size - len(s) % AES.block_size)

    __unpad = lambda self, s: s[0:-ord(s[-1])]

    def encrypt(self, raw):
        raw = self.__pad(raw)
        cipher = AES.new(self.key, AES.MODE_CBC, self.iv)
        return base64.b64encode(cipher.encrypt(raw.encode('utf-8')))

    def decrypt(self, enc):
        enc = base64.b64decode(enc)
        cipher = AES.new(self.key, AES.MODE_CBC, self.iv)
        return self.__unpad(cipher.decrypt(enc).decode("utf-8"))


cipher = AESCipher('SuperSecretKey', 'SuperSecretBLOCK')


print(cipher.encrypt('hola').decode('utf-8'))
```

Comment: Unlike the Python code, the hashes of key and IV are _hex encoded_ in the PHP code. For the key the first 32 bytes are considered (implicitly by `openssl_encypt/decrypt()`) and for the IV the first 16 bytes (explicitly). Also, Base64 encoding/decoding is performed _unnecessarily twice_ (implicitly by `openssl_encypt/decrypt()` and explicitly). The former reduces security the latter is ineffective, i.e. _the fix should be done in the PHP code and not in the Python code_.

Comment: In addition, the PHP code has the following vulnerabilities: A key derivation via a digest is insecure. Also, a static IV is insecure. Instead, a randomly generated IV should be used for each encryption. Regarding the Python code: _PyCryptodome_ supports padding in a dedicated module: [`Crypto.Util.Padding`](https://pycryptodome.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/util/util.html#crypto-util-padding-module).

Comment: Ugh, I already don't like it when there are too many convenience methods, but you know you're working with a stupid library when the "convenient" encoding is performed by default. If you want to adhere to the "Principle of least surprise"  then PHP fails at every corner.